# how to print log output in restFB

Tags: facebook, restfb

i am using restFB framework to do some fb related stuff.  To debug an issue they asked me to provide response json from logs.

But i m not seeing anything in the logs. so how should i enable or what should i write to print the logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like issue with jdev default logging mode.  eclipse print it by default. for jdev you need to enable -Djbo.debugoutput=console